# Question about terminology on topology.

Tags: general-topology, terminology

My professor often says that **every metric space is a topological space**.
But reading the definitions of both terms, it does not make sense to me to state it. That every metric space induces a topological space, I agree. But both are not the same thing. One space has a metric, and the other has a topology. Both things are completely different by definition.

What do you think about it?

This question turns out to be more evident to me when I had to prove that "every metric space is normal". But normal separability is defined on topological spaces...

Comment: When we say that every metric space is a topological space, we mean that every metric space is a topological space with topology induced by the metric. This is just a shorthand.

Comment: Technically, you are correct - they are different categories. But anything you can say about a topological space can be said about a metric space. The important thing is that a metric space coincides with a unique topological space on the same base set. (But two different metrics on the set can give the same topological space.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that the terminology your professor uses might be technically imprecise. Part of the issue here is that in common mathematical parlance, we might use "topological space" to refer to the pair $(X,\tau)$ -- the set of objects and the collection of sets defining the topology -- or just to the set $X$. Similarly, we might use "metric space" to refer to the pair $(X,d)$ -- the set of objects and the distance function on that set -- or just to the set $X$. This is common usage even though in each case the definition is the pair, not just the set $X$. With some experience you'll get used to determining what is meant based on context.

So, what is precisely meant by "every metric space is a topological space" is that the metric induces a topology, as you surmised. What is precisely meant by "every metric space is normal" is that for every metric space $(X,d)$, the topological space $(X,\tau(d))$ -- where $\tau(d)$ is the topology induced by $d$ -- is normal.

Comment: Now, it's clear. Thanks. I hope not to say this in the future though.

Answer (score 2):

Formally speaking you are quite correct. A metric space $(X,d)$ is a very different structure than a topological space $(X,\mathcal{T})$. But the metric *induces* in a standard way a topology $\mathcal{T}_d$ by taking all open balls as a base.

Now we can also see $(X,d)$ as a topological space too, and we can talk about it being normal, Hausdorff, compact, connected and all other notions that are defined for all topological spaces.

It turns out that metric induced topologies are special and have properties that
general spaces need not have. So it's useful to know the topology is actually from a metric. There are even theorems that give necessary and sufficient conditions on a space $X$ to see it can be induced by some metric on $X$, even if you didn't know this by construction.

Being metric allows us to talk about non-topological notions like (total) boundedness, and completeness e.g. And do more "geometric" theory.

Answer (score 1):

Every metric space $(X,d)$ has a *natural topological structure* that arises from the metric.

Namely, given $x\in X$ and $\epsilon\gt 0$, the "open ball with center $x$ and radius $\epsilon$“ is the set
$$B_d(x,\epsilon) = \{y\in X\mid d(x,y)\lt \epsilon\}.$$
A subset $U$ of $X$ is open if and only if it is a union of open balls.

The collection $\tau_d$ of all open subsets of $X$ then forms a topology; this topology is said to be derived from the metric.

So, given $(X,d)$, you use $d$ to define $\tau_d$, and then $(X,\tau_d)$ is a well-defined topological space with underlying set $X$. This is "the" topological structure on $X$ given by the metric $d$.

Answer (score 1):

A metric space is a very special example of a topological space, where the topology is induced by the set of open balls defined by the metric. While not any topological space is a metric space, any metric space is a topological space (and you can thus talk about its topological properties, such as compactness, connectedness, seperability etc.).

This is an example of how you can use a certain structure defined on a set (in this case - a metric function) in order to induce a different structure (i.e - a topology). This allows you to build richer and more complex mathematical objects. It is not uncommon for a mathematical object to have more than one structure defined on it (a topology, a measure, a group structure - you name it), and it is usually interesting to see how those different structures influence one another.

Answer (score 0):

On a metric space a topology is defined by the metric defined open sets.  An open ball of radius $r$ around a point $x$ is defined as all points $y$ such that $d(x,y)\lt r$.  Using standard rules the open ball generate the open sets and that is the topology.  This means every metric space has a topology.